# Stretched and scrollable inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have outer div which contains three other divs as inline-blocks. The 1st and the 3rd are fixed-width while the 2nd should be placed between them. It also should be stretched and have a horizontal scroll bar if its width overflows.

My attempt is

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='center'>
    <div class='inner'>text content</div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>

.container{
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
 }

.left{
  height: 45px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid green; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.right{
  height: 45px;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid orange; 
  display: inline-block;
}

.center{
  height: 45px;
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

It works as expected only if "text content" is of small length. When it overflows, all three inner divs align vertically which is not what I want.
Please, see my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/vxffx7yk/

Comment: I got half of your question, when do you want the horizontal scroll?

Comment: thanks to everybody. All solutions helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sergey I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

If the 1st and 3rd div are fixed width you can assign a width of calc to the inner div.

**Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0dpma9x/)**

I assigned the borders to box-sizing: border-box; so that the extra pixels are not accounted for then assigning the width of calc - the total of the outer divs.

```
.container {
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
.left {
    height: 45px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.right {
    height: 45px;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.center {
    height: 45px;
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
    width: calc(100% - 100px) !important;
    overflow:auto;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do a 3 column with fluid center:

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}
container{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

.left {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}

.center {
    margin: 0 50px;
    background-color:pink;
    height:50px;
    top:0;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.right {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}

.inner{
        
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='left'></div>
    <div class='center'>
      <div class='inner' >Some Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Text, Like really looooooooooooooooooOoOoOooOoOOOooOooooooooOOOoOooooOOoong Some Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Text, Like really looooooooooooooooooOoOoOooOoOOOooOooooooooOOOoOooooOOoong Some Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Text, Like really looooooooooooooooooOoOoOooOoOOOooOooooooooOOOoOooooOOoong Some Loooooooooooooooooooooooong Text, Like really looooooooooooooooooOoOoOooOoOOOooOooooooooOOOoOooooOOoong</div>
    </div>
    <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing the order of elements in your HTML. If the first two elements are floated left and right, the text of the third element will appear between them.

Add `white-space:nowrap` to the third element to prevent the text from wrapping to multiple lines.

```css
.container {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.blockend {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
.blockend-left {
  float: left;
}
.blockend-right {
  float: right;
}
.center {
  background-color: #CCF;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  line-height: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blockend blockend-left"></div>
  <div class="blockend blockend-right"></div>
  <div class="center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi commodo, ipsum sed pharetra gravida, orci magna rhoncus neque, id pulvinar odio lorem non turpis. Nullam sit amet enim.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple. You use percentages to fix the width of the elements!

10% + 80% - (border pixels) + 10%

```css
container{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}

.left{
    height: 45px;
        width: 10%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green; 
    display: inline-block;
}

.right{
    height: 45px;
    width: 10%;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid orange; 
    display: inline-block;
}

.center{
    height: 45px;
    background: blue;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: inline-block;
    width:calc(80% - 5px);
    overflow:auto;
}

.inner{
        
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'></div>
  <div class='center'>
    <div class='inner'>sdfddfgdfgdfgfdgfgfgdfgdfgdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfsdfdssfssdfddfgdfgdfgfdgfgfgdfgdfgdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfsdfdssfssdfddfgdfgdfgfdgfgfgdfgdfgdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddfsdfdssfssdfddfgdfgdfgfdgfgfgdfgdfg</div>
  </div>
  <div class='right'></div>
</div>
```